# Check in and Check Out in Document Management System(DMS)

Tags: dms

What is the exact feature of Check in and Check Out in Document Management System(DMS).
I am little bit confuse with the 'in' and 'out'. Which functionality is actually for what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a system that manages documents, such as [Nuxeo](http://www.nuxeo.com) or [LogicalDOC DMS](http://www.logicaldoc.com) the Check-in could also trigger versioning.

So it would produce a new version of the document using the latest file uploaded. Versioning allows to track changes in a document and get an earlier release.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if this questions belongs here but in laymans term:

> Check Out: is when you permit/disable access to a certain
>   module/document by any other program/user
>
> Check In: is when you save your changes to the server and allow access to the document/module

Comment: @Saikat dont forget to mark this as answer if this already satisfied your question :)